# PHP How to post multiple Form in HTML page to another PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

How to post multiple form in one Html page to  a PHP page 
and parse all the form elemnts in PHP Page 
on a single button click on the Html posting page
any idea thanks in advance

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1"action="abc.php" method="post" name="hoursregistrationform" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="smallBox">
    <div class="smallBox_day">
      <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="monday">Monday:</label>
          <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="monday" name="monday" placeholder="hours">
              <select>
                  <option value="" selected>code</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
              </select>
              <a id="cloneButton" href="#"><img src="images/button_plus_pink.png" alt="+"></a>
          </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
    <a id="cloneButton" href="#"><img src="images/button_plus_pink.png" alt="+"></a>

    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
    <form id="form2" name="form2"action="abc.php" method="post" name="hoursregistrationform" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="smallBox">
    <div class="smallBox_day">
      <div class="control-group">
      ...............................
              <a id="cloneButton" href="#"><img src="images/button_plus_pink.png" alt="+"></a>
          </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
    <a id="cloneButton" href="#"><img src="images/button_plus_pink.png" alt="+"></a>

    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="submit">
    </form>.................................................
.................
```

Comment: provide what you have done?

Comment: bundle the data together e.g. `formdata[form1]=$('#form1').serialize(); formdata[form2]=$('#form2').serialize(); $.ajax({data:formdata, ....});` so when your process it, $_POST['form1'] contains form1's data

Comment: will you @waygood explain me more

Comment: $('#form1').serialize(); will bundle the data together from the form with id="form1".  Since the process should know that this is from form1 we should put it in the formdata array with an index of 'form1'. We can then use ajax to submit the data, or we can construct a new form with jquery and submit it to the php script. The php script should then cycle through $_POST to process each form individually.

Comment: why you need second form though you are not submitting any value and you given name two time its should be one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one global form with the aid of Jquery dynamic form to satisfy your need 
Jquery Dynamic Form:by [clicking here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use one global form, instead of many small forms

Comment: but the requirement is to have multiple forms

Comment: @SamuelJMathew Where does that requirement come from. It seems a bit weird.

Comment: you can do it with single form